# Detecting Enter in TextBox ASP.NET no JavaScript Please

Tags: asp.net, search, textbox, detection, enter

Basically I have a Search Text Box with a LinkButton Control on which the click event is fired. now what i want is when the user type keywords and press enter the Click event got fired.

So No Javascript Only ASP.NET With VB.NET v2.0

Sincerely
Rajeev
Rajeev_rsd@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Create a Panel that contains both the TextBox and LinkButton.  The Panel has a property called DefaultButton, set DefaultButton equal to the ID of the LinkButton.

```
<asp:Panel id="panel" runat="server" DefaultButton="linkButton">
    <asp:TextBox id="search" runat="server"/>
    <asp:LinkButton id="linkButton" runat="server"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use AutoPostback on the textbox?